# Deleting lines from word file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm trying to modify word files which contain questions and explanation under every question
I want to delete all the explanations from the file using **vb.net**.

> **D.** Pull technique

> Performance reports are distributed through the push technique. This means that the project manager distributes the reports regularly through a mechanism, such as email.
> Answer option C is incorrect. One-to-one technique describes a conversation between two people.
> Answer option B is incorrect. Many-to-many technique describes a conversation between many people.
> Answer option D is incorrect. A pull technique describes the recipients of the report "pulling" the information, such as from a website.

> **QUESTION NO:** 5

As shown in the attached text , there are some sentences between last choice "D. TEXT"
and the next question "QUESTION NO: #"
I want to delete all sentences between the last choice and the next question. I tried this code bit it will delete only the line contain the chosen word

```
Try
        Dim objWordApp As word.Application = Nothing
        Dim objDoc As word.Document = Nothing
        Dim TextToFind As String = "Explanation"
        Dim TextRange As word.Range = Nothing
        Dim StringLines As New List(Of String)
        Dim SentenceCount As Integer = 0
        Dim exp As Integer = 0
        objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

        If objWordApp IsNot Nothing Then
            objWordApp.Visible = False
            objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open("E:\Sabbah\PMI SP Files\PMI-SP Questions.doc")
        End If

        If objDoc IsNot Nothing Then
            MsgBox(objDoc.Words.Count.ToString)
            For Each p As word.Paragraph In objDoc.Paragraphs

                TextRange = p.Range
                TextRange.Find.ClearFormatting()
                SentenceCount = TextRange.Sentences.Count

                If SentenceCount > 0 Then
                    Do Until SentenceCount = 0
                        Dim sentence As String = TextRange.Sentences.Item(SentenceCount).Text
                        If sentence.Contains(TextToFind) Then
                            StringLines.Add(sentence.Trim())
                        End If

                        SentenceCount -= 1
                    Loop
                End If
            Next
            If StringLines.Count > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, StringLines.ToArray()))
            End If

            objDoc.Close()
            objWordApp.Quit()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Data.ToString())
    End Try
```

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, why not?

Comment: Why not match on "QUESTION NO:" to the end of the sentence and remove any sentence that doesn't match that pattern?